# winapi scanf printf and data types

Tags: c, winapi

I want to input a string or number from the keyboard and then display it. How do I do it?
This is what I have, gives me all sorts of errors, but nevermind my code, it's just an example. I want to know what the right way to do it is.

Please provide with some code as an example and maybe some links I can further document from.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LPSTR test;

    scanf("%s", &test);
    printf("%s", &test);
    //_getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always remember to use spaces in your code when posting, not tabs, as they do not display correctly here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` reads into a preallocated buffer. It is unsafe with respect to to buffer overflows unless you specify a field width, e.g. `"%50s"`.

Likewise, `printf( "%s", str )` takes a pointer to the first character of the string for `str`.

You are passing a pointer to pointer, so I presume you expect the functions to do memory management for you. `scanf` will never call `malloc`.

```
char testbuf[ 51 ]; // allocate space for 50 characters + termination
LPSTR test = testbuf;

scanf("%50s", test); // read at most 50 characters
printf("%s", test);
//_getch();
return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I posted another question if you would be so nice to help me again.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956302/how-do-you-define-a-constant-in-winapi

Answer (score 2):

Because you have not allocated any memory to `test`, you have a few options:

1. change your declaration of `test` to a `char` array:
    `char test[64];`
2. allocated some memory for `test` by using malloc:
    `LPSTR test = malloc(64 * sizeof(*test));`

Also, this line is wrong:

```
scanf("%s", &test);
```

It should just be

```
scanf("%s", test);
```

You do not need the address of a character array when using `scanf()`, and any decent compiler should give you a warning there.